# Check the dialog is visible - Espresso

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I found on Stackoverflow something like that about checking when dialog is visible:

```
 onView(withText("Yes"))
                    .inRoot(isDialog())
                    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                    .perform(click());
```

Of course this works if Dialog with button 'yes' is visible, but in different scenario, if dialog will be invisible I got crash:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Yes"

So how to write that if the dialog exists, click yes, and if it does not exist, then nothing will be clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
  onView(withText("Yes")).inRoot(isDialog()).withFailureHandler(new FailureHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Throwable error, Matcher<View> viewMatcher){

            }
        }).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(customClick());

//if dialog is visible, perform click, otherwise do nothing.
```